# ActiveRecord OUTER JOIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, outer-join, arel

In a Google Group, I've added my question - [here infact](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyonrails-talk/kHYW5cid11A/30jBs25zl84J)!

My question is how to express this outer join 'the Rails way':

```
SELECT 
`employees`.`id` AS t0_r0, `employees`.`name` AS t0_r1, `employees`.`last_seen` AS t0_r2, `employees`.`created_at` AS t0_r3, `employees`.`updated_at` AS t0_r4, `employees`.`punch_clock_id` AS t0_r5, `employees`.`account_id` AS t0_r6, `employees`.`born_at` AS t0_r7, `entrances`.`id` AS t1_r0, `entrances`.`employee_id` AS t1_r1, `entrances`.`clocked_at` AS t1_r2, `entrances`.`created_at` AS t1_r3, `entrances`.`updated_at` AS t1_r4, `entrances`.`entrance_type` AS t1_r5 
FROM 
    `employees` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `entrances` ON `entrances`.`employee_id` = `employees`.`id` AND (`entrances`.`clocked_at` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31’) 
WHERE 
    `employees`.`account_id` = 2
```

My first take was:

```
current_user.account.employees.includes(:entrances).where( 'entrances.clocked_at' => @month_range)
```

but that does only provide for employees with entrances (unless I loose the 'where' part of the statement, in which case I do get all employees (and all 250K entrances!!!))

Comment: thank you @xlembouras for editing my question to present the SELECT statement in a proper way! Tried my best but the editor would not allow me to "circumclude" the statement with the correct accent grave - like the help instructed me to :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include `employees` with no `entrances` you'll have to explicitly include that case in your `where` statement by calling `entrances.id IS NULL`.

```
current_user.account.employees.includes(:entrances).where( 'entrances.id IS NULL OR entrances.clocked_at = ?', @month_range)
```

That last part might look slightly different depending on what `@month_range` contains.

Comment: sorry to not having replied :(

but your suggestion does not compile, I'm afraid

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'entrances.id' in 'where clause': SELECT `employees`.* FROM `employees`  WHERE `employees`.`account_id` = 2 AND (entrances.id IS NULL OR entrances.clocked_at = '2015-02-18')`